# provide a power query technique / DAX query in powerBI to Fill the values in the column

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

[image]

Now I have an **id** column
I want the value **x1** to be inserted in the blank cells, till the x2 does not come in the picture(i.e till 10th row).

whenever x2 come into the picture, then it needs to be filled **x2** value in their particular blank cells(i.e till 18th row)

and the same thing continues for x3 and x4 values as well.

please provide a DAX measure/ or any other technique to get this type of result in powerbi, thanks.

Note: I have 40000 rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Fill Down](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/fill-values-column) in Power Query before you load the data into the dataset.

Comment: i have 40000 rows. is it possible to fill like that?

Comment: Sure, that should be no problem.